# Terraform cannot ssh into EC2 instance to upload files

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to get a basic terraform example up and running and then push a very simple flask application in a docker container there. The script all works if I remove the file provisioner section and the user data section. The pem file is in the same location on my disk as the `main.tf` script and the `terraform.exe` file.

If I leave the file provisioner in then the script fails with the following error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_launch_configuration.example: 1 error(s) occurred:

* dial tcp :22: connectex: No connection could be made because the target    machine actively refused it.
```

If I remove the file provisioning section the script runs fine and I can ssh into the created instance using my private key so the `key_name` part seems to be working ok, I think its to do with the file provisioner trying to connect to add my files.

Here is my launch configuration from my script, I have tried using the connection block which I got from another post online but I cant see what I am doing wrong.

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "example" {
  image_id = "${lookup(var.eu_west_ami, var.region)}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = "Terraform-python"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "python/hello_flask.py"
    destination = "/home/ec2-user/hello_flask.py"
    connection {
        type     = "ssh"
        user     = "ec2-user"       
        private_key = "${file("Terraform-python.pem")}"
        timeout = "2m"
        agent = false
    }
  }
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "python/flask_dockerfile"
    destination = "/home/ec2-user/flask_dockerfile" 
    connection {
        type     = "ssh"
        user     = "ec2-user"       
        private_key = "${file("Terraform-python.pem")}"
        timeout = "2m"
        agent = false
    }
  }
  user_data = <<-EOF
          #!/bin/bash
          sudo yum update -y
          sudo yum install -y docker
          sudo service docker start
          sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
          sudo docker build -t flask_dockerfile:latest /home/ec2-user/flask_dockerfile
          sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask_dockerfile
          EOF
  lifecycle {
     create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

It is probably something very simple and stupid that I am doing, thanks in advance for anyone that takes a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws_launch_configuration` is not an actual EC2 instance but just a 'template' to launch instances. Thus, it is not possible to connect to it via SSH.

To copy those file you have two options:

- Creating a custom AMI. For that, you can use [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) or Terraform itself, launching an EC2 instance with `aws_instance` and these file provisioners, and creating an AMI from it with `aws_ami`
- The second one is not a best practice but if the files are short, you can include them in the `user_data`.

Comment: So if I chose to pursue option one can I then use newly created aws_instance inside the aws_launch_configuration block still or would this part of my script need to be rewritten?

Comment: You first set up an aws_instance, then create an aws_ami from it, and finally you can use that ami in aws_launch_configuration

Comment: Do you have a link to a github or a tutorial which demonstrates how to do this? From the documentation its not clear how you use the aws_instance in the aws_ami block nor how you then use it in the launch configuration. I have created the aws_instance for my docker instance but cannot work out how to use it.

Comment: I had a go at what I think you meant but it doesnt seem to work, at least what I have tried! I created an aws_instance and that works ok, I then created an ami from that using aws_ami_from_instance which also seems to work but there doesnt seem to a way to get the launch config to use it. The docs say that all properties from aws_ami are exposed but it doesnt seem to like ami_id. If you have a working example I would very much like to see it.

Comment: Yes the aws_ami resource does export the ami id: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ami.html#attributes-reference   Then you can use it in the `image_id` attribute of `aws_launch_configuration`

Comment: Ive got it all hooked up and working but two observations. One is that the extra instance thats used as a template is started up each time I build. And secondly its only this one that has any of the user data based bits present on it. For instance now 3 containers start on build, but only that one has docker installed, its as if the template is used before the user data is applied? However the user data never runs again on the images built from it, I think this is by default?